# Connecting Firebase results in NoSuchMethodError in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I'm a beginner at mobile dev and this is my first project to connect to Firebase
I tried to create a project and set up Firebase from [Firebase Push Notifications in .NET MAUI](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e)
but I can't finish the tutorial, because the exception appeared (`NoSuchMethodError`). Then I tried to find a solution for this, until now I haven't seen the solution and I have no idea what happened and why.
Please, tell me what to do and why is it.

[image: 1]

I try to get a Token from my app but for now, I just need to make my app run without the exception and expect to know what happened.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code and error messages as images, always use text instead. Please also read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I see the blog, they used `Plugin.Firebase` Nuget Package. Do you use this third-party tool as well?

Tips:
Push notification works on a .net MAUI app with the existing [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base)`net6.0-android31.0`and [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging)`net6.0-android31.0` libraries. Since they use only platform-specific events and code and do not have a reference to `Xamarin.Forms` or `.NET MAUI`, you can even leverage those.

Comment: yeah, I did install it in my project via the dotnet CLI instead.

Did you mean that I should use Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging instead of Plugin.Firebase?
The first step that I need is to connect Firebase with my Muai project I just need to know how it works and prove that it can

the connecting example that I have is with using Plugin.Firebase